Why does the exact same version of Google Chrome work via proxy on one machine and does not work on another?
I have two Windows 10 machines with exactly the same Google Chrome version 131.0.6778.205 64 bit.
I run Google Chrome with proxy on these machines with the following command
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --proxy-server=https://mywebsite.com:1234

On one machine Google Chrome works via proxy — it asks proxy credentials and I can see that my IP address changes.
On the other it works without proxy — it does not ask for proxy credentials and opens all the websites with my real IP address.
How is it possible?
What can be the difference?
See this blog post for info on how I configured the proxy on the server side.

Are the machines on the same network? Do they have any pre-existing proxy settings in inetcpl.cpl for example?

@grawity The machines are on different networks. I am not sure about all the settings, but at least there is no proxy on the both machines.
